# React: append to a state array object's array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

My state looks something like this:

```
const [state, setState] = useState([
 { id: uuidv4(), myList: ["listItem1", "listItem2"] }
 { id: uuidv4(), myList: ["listItem1"] }
])
```

How can I add a value to `myList` to the specific object that I want it added?

Comment: How will you identity the specific object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as you need do compute uuid to generate the ids, I would use a function to initialize the state :

```
const [state, setState] = useState(() => [
 { id: uuidv4(), myList: ["listItem1", "listItem2"] }
 { id: uuidv4(), myList: ["listItem1"] }
])
```

Then, to add an item to the `myList` array, I suggest you to add a function like below :

```
function addItem(id, item) {
  const newState = state.map(el => 
      el.id === id ? {...el, myList: [...el.myList, item]} : el
  );
  setState(newState);
}
```